# How to divide a data frame into groups of a predefined size while keeping each category of a variable represented in each group

Tags: r, dplyr, split, subset, cross-validation

I am having trouble doing cross-validation for a hierarchical dataset. There is a level 2 factor ("ID") that needs to be equally represented in each subset. For this dataset, there are 157 rows and 28 IDs. I want to divide my data up into five subsets, each containing 31 rows, where each of the 28 IDs is represented (a stand can be repeated within a subset).

I have gotten as far as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
```

and have no clue where to take it from there. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do: assign one row from each ID randomly to each of the 5 subsets, and then distribute the leftovers fully randomly. Without sample data this is untested, but it should at least get you on the right track.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    random_rank = rank(runif(n())),
    strata = ifelse(random_rank <= 5, random_rank, sample(1:5, size = n(), replace = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  select(-random_rank) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This should create a `strata` column as described above. If you want to split the data into a list of data frames for each strata, `... %>% group_by(strata) %>% group_split()`.